# The CSS property 'position' doesn't work on ConvertAPI

Tags: php, pdf, css-position, pdf-conversion, convertapi

I use the html to PDF conversion via PHP integration with ConvertAPI.
Since 2022/12/07 i'm having troubles with 'position' CSS property.
All of my templates that are converted are fully based on 'position: absolute;'.

Now all the elements are concentrated on the the first page, no longer positioned by template pages as it always worked.

These are the properties that I use in the request

```
$result = ConvertApi::convert('pdf', [
        'File' => $file,
        'ViewportWidth' => '1200',
        'ViewportHeight' => '1554',
        'PageRange' => '1-' . $page_numbers,
        'MarginTop' => '0',
        'MarginRight' => '0',
        'MarginBottom' => '0',
        'MarginLeft' => '0',
    ], 'html'
);
```

I already tried to use the 'FixedElements' property from ConvertAPI, but none of options changed anything, as if the parameter was not working.

Comment: Sounds like you should contact the support of that API's provider then.

Comment: Could you check if your html file is rendered correctly in Chrome 108 print preview? Important to set margins to 0.

Comment: And page size set to a4